# Size of the HTMLFields tinyMCE in Django

Tags: django, tinymce, rich-text-editor

I've just recently success to install tinyMCE the text editor and to use the HTMLField. [image: The HTMLFIELDD in Django admin]

But as you can see the area is not that big and I would like to make it bigger. I also have another question but this one is less important, I put all the tool in my editor but I can't see "code sample" so I'm wondering is there any tips to add it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In setting.py just add:

```
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'plugins': "table,xhtmlxtras,paste,searchreplace",
    'theme': "advanced",
    "theme_advanced_buttons3_add" : "cite,abbr",
    'cleanup_on_startup': True,
    'custom_undo_redo_levels': 10,
    'theme_advanced_buttons1': "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    'theme_advanced_buttons2': "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
    'theme_advanced_buttons3': "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
    'theme_advanced_buttons4': "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak",
    'extended_valid_elements': "iframe[src|title|width|height|allowfullscreen|frameborder|webkitAllowFullScreen|mozallowfullscreen|allowFullScreen]",
    'theme_advanced_toolbar_location': "top",
    'theme_advanced_toolbar_align': "left",
    'theme_advanced_statusbar_location': "bottom",
    'theme_advanced_resizing': True,
}
```